# Nullable FK vs two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a requirement to store all scan (barcode/fingerprint etc) events to a table, and if it's a scan that is linked to a person who is in the database, link the scan to that person. So, I need to store invalid scans as well.

I have a few options.

A UserScan table, with the details about the scan, and a nullable UserID foreign key to the User table, which is only populated when we have a valid scan.

or

A UserScan table with all the details about the scan, and a NOT NULL FK to the User Table, and only write valid scans to this table, plus a 'failed scan' table, with details about the scan only.

Maybe there's other options?

This table will be rather large, and a lot of queries will be using this table to work out who is in what location at certain times, for example. Will the nullable UserID be a less optimal option? Or is that recommended?

I was thinking of maybe a 'Scan Event' table, which has all the scans, and IF the scan is successful, a UserScanEvent table, with the Scan Event ID and the User ID. But that looks like a many-to-many link table.

I'm looking for the best design for efficiency. Which is the best way to go, and maybe there's a better idea?

Comment: How do you link an invalid scan for a user? He identify himself before the scan?

Comment: No, sorry - an invalid scan would be the number on the scanned card did not match any person. For example, for a finger print, the fingerprint data did not match a person. Or, for a barcode, the barcode number was not matched to any valid person.

Comment: Then your second option would be much better (a table for valid and a table for invalid) since the invalid data will not relate with users You will have much more consistent data. And querying on it will be related or not related to users which will improve the search since it will be specific. E.g. search in one table with say 4kk registries (valid and invalid) for user information will be much slower than a table with 1kk registries (only valids) and, only if needed, search for invalid data in a table with the other 3kk registries.

Comment: I've added it as a comment because I think your question is primarily opinion-based even though I didn't mark it so.

Comment: All three options are valid. "Efficiency" depends on what you are going to do with this data. What kind of queries/reports you are going to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
I think that from the select efficiency point of view, option 1 might give you the best result, using a filtered index on the `userId` column in the `UserScan` table.

**Option 2:**
Your second option is probably the worst option since it means you will have two almost identical table structures in your database, and that's a bad design.

**Option 3:**
On the academic level, option 3 is the way to go. Nullable columns are frowned upon in the relational model. To prevent the `UserScanEvent` table from creating a many to many relationship between scans and persons, add a unique constraint on the `scanId` column. this way, each scan in this table can only be associated with a single person.

**To sum up:**
Having said all that, Select efficiency is a tricky thing to predict. My hunch tells me that option 1, while might not be the best fit to the relational model, will enable faster select executes then option 3, but as Jorge Campos wrote in his comment, it is merely my opinion, it's not something I can say for sure.